# Understanding a proof of the problem: For, $x\ge 0$ define, $f(x)=\frac1{x+2\cos x}.$ Determine the set, $\{ y \in \mathbb{R}: y=f(x), x\ge 0\}.$

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation

For, $x\ge 0$ define, $f(x)=\frac1{x+2\cos x}.$ Determine the set, $$\{ y \in \mathbb{R}: y=f(x), x\ge 0\}.$$

I am having trouble in understanding, a particular solution of this problem. I am attaching the solution below:

We start by analyzing $g(x)=x+2\cos x.$ We have, $g'(x)=1-2\sin x$ and $g''(x)=-2\cos x.$ We first, limit out study of this function $g$ in the interval $[0, \pi].$ In that range, $$g'\left(\frac{\pi}6\right)=g'\left(\frac{5\pi}6\right)=0.$$ But, $g''\left(\frac{5\pi}6\right) > 0$ and $g''\left(\frac{\pi}6\right) < 0.$ Hence, $g(x)$ is increasing from $x=0$ attaining a local maxima at, $x=\frac{\pi}6$ it decreases. Then it attains a local minima at $x=\frac{5\pi}6$ and again increases. Hence $$\min_{0\le x\le \pi} g(x) =\min \left\{ g(0), g\left(\frac{5\pi}6\right)\right\} =\frac{5\pi}6-\sqrt3.$$ For $x\gt \pi$ we have, $g(x)=x+2\cos x>\pi -2 > \frac{5\pi}6-\sqrt3$

For  we have $\min_{x\ge 0} g(x) =\frac{5\pi}6-\sqrt3=t.$ Again, $f(x)$ is continuous and $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x) =\infty$. This enables us to conclude that $g$ attains all real values greater than $t$ . So, the required set is $$T=\left\{ x | x \in \mathbb{R}, 0<x\le \frac1{\frac{5\pi}6-\sqrt3} \right\}$$

In this proof, I dont understand the reason of how the statement " For $x\gt \pi$ we have, $g(x)=x+2\cos x>\pi -2$" ? Is this some kind of a formula/theorem ?

Answer (score 1):

> In this proof, I dont understand the reason of how the statement " For $x\gt \pi$ we have, $g(x)=x+2\cos x>\pi -2$" ? Is this some kind of a formula/theorem ?

The proof used the fact that we always have $\cos x\ge -1$.

So, we always have
$$\color{red}{2\cos x\ge -2}$$

So, for $$\color{green}{x\gt \pi}$$
we have
$$\color{green}x\color{red}{+2\cos x}\gt \color{green}{\pi} \color{red}{-2}$$